# SVN log file and TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm attempting to generate an SVN log file through TortoiseSVN, if that is even possible.

I would use the command line

```
svn log --verbose --xml
```

but this won't work since it is a remote repo and I can't define a username/password for it (gets ignored by svn)

Is there an equivalent log file generator for TortoiseSVN?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tortoise displays the log by the command:
right-click/TortoiseSVN/Show Log

But I'm not sure what you mean by "this won't work since it is a remote repo and I can't define a username/password for it".  SVN accepts username and password parameters:

```
svn log --verbose --xml --username <user> --password <password>
```

Comment: Right, sorry for the confusion.  for example, if I do
    svn log --verbose --xml --username greg --password pass123

it will request from the server, and it will ask

MojaveStormPC@remotesvnsite.edu password:

So, it seems as if the SVN is ignoring the given parameters and taking my pc name as username, and requesting another password.  As my computer name isn't registered on the server (which I have no control over) I am unable to get the log file.   Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to set the authentication parameters inside TortoiseSVN.  If Tortoise isn't prompting you for credentials, you need to clear the existing authentication (which forgets everything, be forewarned) and then it will prompt you.  You can do so with right-click/TortoiseSVN/Settings, then click on "Saved Data", then click "Authentication Data - Clear".  William's post is post-on, which is why it is +1 for me.

Answer (score -3):

Right click on the project -> Show log -> Statistics

It shows 4 types of charts. This with SVN 1.7

[image]